# How to extract .gz file Dynamically in Java?

Tags: java

In http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml lots of urls of .gz-files are given, like this:

```
<loc>
    http://www.newegg.com//Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product01.xml.gz
</loc>
```

I want to extract these dynamically. I don't want to store them locally, I just want to extract them and store the contained data in a database.

Modify:

I am getting exception

```
private void processGzip(URL url, byte[] response) throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException, UnknownFormatException {

        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Processing gzip");

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);

        // Remove .gz ending
        String xmlUrl = url.toString().replaceFirst("\\.gz$", "");

        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("XML url = " + xmlUrl);

        InputStream decompressed = new GZIPInputStream(is);
        InputSource in = new InputSource(decompressed);
        in.setSystemId(xmlUrl);         
        processXml(url, in);
        decompressed.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the input stream in [`GZIPInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html), and it'll decompress the data as you're reading it.

Comment: private void processGzip(URL url, byte[] response) throws MalformedURLException,
   IOException, UnknownFormatException {
  
  if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Processing gzip");
  
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
  
  // Remove .gz ending
  String xmlUrl = url.toString().replaceFirst("\\.gz$", "");
  
  if (DEBUG) System.out.println("XML url = " + xmlUrl);

  InputStream decompressed = new GZIPInputStream(is);
  InputSource in = new InputSource(decompressed);
  in.setSystemId(xmlUrl);   
  processXml(url, in);
  decompressed.close();
 }

Comment: java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user1047251: All this means is that the data you're giving it is not in the gzip format. Try saving it to a file and using `gunzip` on the command line to see if that works (it almost certainly won't).

Comment: I am getting exception in InputStream decompressed = new GZIPInputStream(is);
line please help me how to fix it.. Thanks