# How to extract the online zip url in Java

Tags: java, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract .gz file Dynamically in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151275/how-to-extract-gz-file-dynamically-in-java)

I need to extract the zip file Dynamically I don't want to store zip file in my system.

Example:

In http://www.newegg.com/Siteindex_USA.xml site is having lots of zip file url like

`<loc>
http://www.newegg.com//Sitemap/USA/newegg_sitemap_product01.xml.gz
</loc>`

I need to extract this zip file dynamically. After extracting this zip file it will extract the .xml file I need to read that xml file for all the link and store in file.

Please someone help me in this I need this part of code to develop my crawler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ZipInputStream` that wraps `InputStream` that you get from `URLConnection.open()`.